# When is the manifold hypothesis violated?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, manifold-learning

If the high-dimensional dataset is of full rank, like an N samples by N features matrix, will the manifold hypothesis be violated? i.e. we cannot assume those data live on a lower-dimensional space?

Comment: Do you mean to have the same number of samples as features?

Comment: Could you state what you mean by "the manifold hypothesis"?  Your use of a negative in "we cannot assume" could be interpreted in two diametrically opposite ways!

Comment: Yes, I mean the number of samples is the same as features; The manifold hypothesis means we can learn a low-dimensional representation of high-dimensional data.